# How to loop through ALL pages?

Tags: loop, pages

Is it possible to loop through all the pages in a website? If so, how?

I'm building a one-pager resume website, and I want to display all of the website's pages as parts of my main page.

Comment: why is it down voted? It is a good question

Comment: I've no idea. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to learn how to do it.

Here's a solution:

```
$pages = get_pages();
foreach($pages as $page) {
    echo($page->post_content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about something like this:

```
   $pages = get_pages(); 
   foreach ($pages as $page) {
       echo $page->post_title;
   }
```

?

Of course you can sort them (`sort_column`, `sort_order`), filter out (`exclude`) unwanted etc. by using specific arguments applied to `get_pages()` function - you can check them in the [Wordpress docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest doing this:

```
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'page'));

while (have_posts()) { 
    the_post();
    get_template_part( 'templates/list/content', 'xxx' );
}

wp_reset_query();
```

Doing this you will be able to use

```
get_template_part( 'templates/list/content', 'xxx' );
```

Comment: you should never use `query_posts`

Comment: @MarkKaplun and why is that?

Comment: because it s a horrible kludge which will break pagination and make even more unexpected fun. google for it